# Creating/retrieving updated data while testing Firebase Cloud Functions with firebase-functions-test and mocha

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have the following data

```
{
  users: {
    "user1": {
        "fieldA": 0
    }
  },
  tasks: {
    "task1": {
        "fieldC": false    }
  }
}
```

I have an onUpdate Firebase Cloud Function that is fired after a write on a document within the **tasks** collection. If **fieldC** becomes true, **fieldA**  will be incremented by 1.

How would I retrieve the **user1** document so that I can test the updated values?

I imagine the following scenario:

1. Retrieve **user1** document.
2. Execute test
3. Retrieve new **user1** document
4. Compare old and new values

**What have I tried?**

First I tried searching the *firebase-functions-test* module to find a way to retrieve a document at a specific path.

Secondly, I tried initializing an instance of Firestore. After implementing the following

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin);
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

I receive the error:  **Error: The default Firebase app already exists. This means you called initializeApp() more than once...** which makes sense.

Please let me know if you need more information.

The question is: **How would I retrieve the **user1** document so that I can test the updated values?**

**Cloud Function**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();
const fcfDocumentRetriever = require('tht-fcf-document-retriever');

exports.onBetUpdate = functions.firestore.document('wagers/{betId}').onUpdate(handleOnUpdate);

async function handleOnUpdate(snapshot, context) {
    let oldData = snapshot.before.data();
    let newData = snapshot.after.data();

    // Bet moved from 'In Progress' to 'Awaiting Consequence' phase, i.e., a loser was specified and media was uploaded
    if (oldData.status === 0 && newData.status === 1) { 
        return await updateParticipantsRecords(newData);
    }
}

// Update **user1** in the above scenario given **task1**
async function updateParticipantsRecords(bet) {
    const participants = await fcfDocumentRetriever.getDocumentsWithCriteria(db, 'users', 'username', 'in', bet.participants);
    let updatedParticipants = {};
    const participantsAfterSideOneUpdate = await updateWinLossRecord(bet.sideOne, participants.data);
    const participantsAfterSideTwoUpdate = await updateWinLossRecord(bet.sideTwo, participants.data);
    updatedParticipants = {...participantsAfterSideOneUpdate, ...participantsAfterSideTwoUpdate};
    return updatedParticipants;
}

async function updateWinLossRecord(team, participants) {
    const updatedParticipants = {};
    for (let user of team.users) {
        for (let participant of participants) {
            if (participant.username === user) {
                if (team.didWin) {
                    participant.wins += 1;
                    await updateDocument("users", user, { wins: participant.wins });
                } else {
                    participant.losses += 1;
                    await updateDocument("users", user, { losses: participant.losses });
                }
                updatedParticipants[user] = participant;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return updatedParticipants;
}

async function updateDocument(collection, documentId, fieldsToUpdate) {
    return await db.collection(collection).doc(documentId).update(fieldsToUpdate)
        .then(doc => {
            return doc;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return err;
        });
}
```

**Test**

```
const projectConfig = {
    databaseURL: ****,
    projectId: ****,
};

const test = require('firebase-functions-test')(projectConfig, './app-test-key.json');

describe('Cloud Functions', async () => {
    let myFunctions;
    
    before(() => {
        myFunctions = require('../index');
    })

    after(() => {
        test.cleanup();
    });

    describe('participants should be updated', () => {
        it('should return an object of participants with their updated records ', () => {
           // retrieved updated user1 document to test
        })
    });
})
```

Comment: I don't understand at all. You already update the counter for `user1`, you want to test the value was updated? If not, what you want to test? The question is not clear.

Comment: Yes, we would need much more info: can you add to your question the code of the CF and of the test (Mocha)?

Comment: @FerVelvet Yes I want to test the value of was updated

Comment: @RenaudTarnec What would the code help with? This is the functionality: *I have an onUpdate Firebase Cloud Function that is fired after a write on a document within the tasks collection. If fieldC becomes true, fieldA will be incremented by 1.* The CF works. I just need to retrieve ```user1``` and test it's newly updated values. Also, the test is irrelevant in this case as I don't need help with the logic, just retrieving the user document

Comment: Cloud Function code can be tricky to be written correctly, especially in terms of life cycle and termination management. Depending on how it is done there might be some "mysterious” behaviour because sometimes the platform might cleanup the function before its completion. I have doubts that you will receive an answer without sharing **all** the code, because without it is nearly impossible to give a sensible answer.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @RenaudTarnec added